# WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Logger with qualifiers @Default

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, websphere-liberty, java-ee-8

I have upgraded the project from Java EE to Jakarta. As a server, I am using Liberty. I got the following error after the project and server upgrade:

```
CWWKZ0002E: An exception occurred while starting the application co2datenservice.webapp. The exception message was: com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Logger with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private com.hocome.service.measure.MeasureTimeInterceptor.logger
  at com.hocome.service.measure.MeasureTimeInterceptor.logger(MeasureTimeInterceptor.java:0)
```

I have configured bean discovery mode to "all". What could be the cause of the project? Could you give me a hit?

I used the same server as before but some upgrades in featureManager elements. Here is my featureManager configuration: [image]

The project runs in my old notebook and other teammates' notebook setups. I looked through all configurations but could not find any difference.

Comment: What Liberty features do you have active (i.e. configured in your server.xml as children of the `<featureManager>` element) ?  Are you saying you were using Liberty before, in the previous, working (Java EE) configuration ?  (Or were you using some other server then)?  If you were using Liberty before can you please list the features you were using before vs. now?

Comment: I used the same server Liberty before but some dependency upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

The only change between CDI 2.0 and CDI 3.0 should be the use of the new jakarta packages in the API (vs. the old javax packages).

Can you look for the class which provides the `Logger` bean and see how it's annotated? Check whether its annotations are from the `jakarta` package or the `javax` package.

E.g. if it's an application scoped bean, it should be annotated with `jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped` and not `javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped`.

If there are places in your code which are still using classes from the `javax` packages in the [JavaEE 8 API](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/), you need to change them all to use the `jakarta` packages from the [Jakarta EE 9 API](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/). The is usually a straighforward find and replace operation, though you may also have files in `META-INF/services` which need to be renamed.

If the annotated class is in a third-party library it's a bit more difficult. You either need to see if the library has released a version which is compatible with Jakarta EE 9, or use a tool like [Eclipse Transformer](https://github.com/eclipse/transformer) to create a modified version of their jars which use `jakarta` instead of `javax`.

Comment: I checked the class all annotations are from Jakarta. Is it possible the problem is because of the project configurations? Because the project is running in my old notebook